# IIS 7.5 setting SSL to ignored equal to accept any certificate

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-7, https, requiressl

In IIS7.5, for my web application, if I set the "Require SSL" checked and select Client certificate to "Ignore", is it equal to accepting any SSL certificate and authenticating request from client with ANY certificate?